# Simple css override

Tags: html, css

I have the following css:

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I want to create another class which **inherit all** `wrapper` **properties** and overrides the `width` property:

```
.wrapper .extended {
    width: 150% !important;
}
```

And tried to use that in my HTML like:

```
<section class="wrapper extended">
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work.

How can I correct my code ?

Comment: you are going for the child's, concatenate that.

Comment: lol, remove the space between your classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove space between `.wrapper` `.extended` class

```
.wrapper.extended {
    width: 150% !important;
}
```

[css selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors)

Answer (score 3):

They are two classes of same element. Remove the space:

```
.wrapper.extended {
    width: 150% !important;
}
```

Giving `.wrapper .extended` means, you are selecting a child `.extended` under `.wrapper`. Giving `.wrapper.extended` is you are selecting an element with both `.wrapper` and `.extended` classes. Hope it is clear.

Comment: @PraveenKumar you explain well !!

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a space between these 2 classes. `.wrapper .extended`

It will be considered as it's child element, but it is not. Use this

```
.wrapper.extended {
    width: 150% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove space between `.wrapper` `.extended` class

Please add this method `.wrapper.extended`

And css like this:

```
.wrapper.extended {
    width: 150% !important;
}
```

Hope it is clear.